# The type or namespace name 'Skeleton' could not be found

Tags: c#, kinect

I am trying to set up a kinect sensor (the old version - v1) with Visual Studio 2015. I did download the SDK v2.0.

I am trying to build a gesture detector class. I found some source code online that uses the Skeleton class. However, I keep getting these errors.

The type or namespace name 'Skeleton' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Description
The type or namespace name 'SkeletonFrameReadyEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Description
The type or namespace name 'SkeletonPoint' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skeleton is replaced by the Body class in v.2.0

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.kinect.body.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn799273.aspx

Comment: Cool. What about DepthImageFrame and ColorImageFrame. I am getting similar errors too.